# Xorg server won't start after fresh install of Debian 5.04, screen goes blank (Intel Atom D510(Pinetrail) on Intel D510MO)

Tags: linux, debian, debian-lenny, xorg, central-processing-unit

I have installed Debian 5.04 Lenny on my new Intel D510MO motheboard. I fixed some issues with incorrect drive mapping (for some reason during installation my hdd was on sdb, after a restart it is under sda - fixed in grub), and now I am struggling with getting graphical enviroment up and running, I installed the graphical enviroment using the Debian installer. I am not an linux expert by any means, I assume that I need to edit the xorg.conf file.

Any hints appreciated!

UPDATE1:

No change after `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

Here is my current xorg.conf:

```
# xorg.conf (X.Org X Window System server configuration file)
#
# This file was generated by dexconf, the Debian X Configuration tool, using
# values from the debconf database.
#
# Edit this file with caution, and see the xorg.conf manual page.
# (Type "man xorg.conf" at the shell prompt.)
#
# This file is automatically updated on xserver-xorg package upgrades *only*
# if it has not been modified since the last upgrade of the xserver-xorg
# package.
#
# If you have edited this file but would like it to be automatically updated
# again, run the following command:
#   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Generic Keyboard"
    Driver      "kbd"
    Option      "XkbRules"  "xorg"
    Option      "XkbModel"  "pc105"
    Option      "XkbLayout" "pl"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Configured Mouse"
    Driver      "mouse"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
EndSection
```

UPDATE2:

I have installed vnc4server package. I can connect over vnc from my windows 7 laptop and i see empty desktop with terminal window open. Seems that the xserver and gdm are running but they cant talk with my GPU. I am not sure if a can use any gui tool to configure it overthe vnc, as all I see is the terminal window, no taskbars etc.

UPDATE3:

My current Xorg.0.log http://pastebin.pl/18918
The graphic chipset integrated into the D510 processor is Intel 945GC

Answer (score 1):

Run `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` as root or via sudo, accept the defaults if you're not sure. Then reboot.

If you could post an error message etc also?

Comment: I updated my question. I cant see any errors, screen just goes blank when I am on virtual terminal 7.